# AngularDart hangs with loading

Tags: nginx, angular-dart

Just build with:

```
pub get
webdev build
```

And copied to nginx server, then it hangs in the browser saying `"Loading..."`

Update: It looks like a `<base href="/">` and rewrite problem?

Comment: Any output in the browser console?

Comment: - - [05/Oct/2018:07:37:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 376 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" ""